# Parsing key value IPV6 pair

Tags: antlr4

I have following input format IP:FE80:CD00::211E:729C to parse.

After parsing, I want Key as IP: and value as FE80:CD00::211E:729C

I have defined following grammar

```
grammar IPV6;
keyValue  : KEY ip_v6_address;

ip_v6_address
 : h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | h16? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | ((h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | (((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | ((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' ls32
 | (((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' ls32
 | ((((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16
;

h16
 : hexdig hexdig hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig
;

hexdig
 : digit
 | (A | B | C | D | E | F)
;

ls32
 : h16 ':' h16
 | ip_v4_address
;

ip_v4_address
 : dec_octet '.' dec_octet '.' dec_octet '.' dec_octet
;

dec_octet
 : digit
 | non_zero_digit digit
 | D1 digit digit
 | D2 (D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4) digit
 | D2 D5 (D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5)
;

digit
 : D0
 | non_zero_digit
;

non_zero_digit
 : D1
 | D2
 | D3
 | D4
 | D5
 | D6
 | D7
 | D8
 | D9
;

D0 : '0';
D1 : '1';
D2 : '2';
D3 : '3';
D4 : '4';
D5 : '5';
D6 : '6';
D7 : '7';
D8 : '8';
D9 : '9';

A : 'a'|'A';
B : 'b'|'B';
C : 'c'|'C';
D : 'd'|'D';
E : 'e'|'E';
F : 'f'|'F';

KEY: '['? STRING SPACE* STRING']'?':';

fragment SPACE : ' ';
fragment STRING: [a-zA-Z0-9/._-]+;
WS  : [ \t\r\n] + -> skip;
```

The above grammar gives me following tokens after running against the above example

```
[TOKENS]
  KEY                  'IP:'
  KEY                  'FE80:'
  KEY                  'CD00:'
  ':'                  ':'
  KEY                  '211E:'
  D7                   '7'
  D2                   '2'
  D9                   '9'
  C                    'C'
  EOF                  '<EOF>'
[PARSE-TREE]
line 1:3 mismatched input 'FE80:' expecting {'::', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', A, B, C, D, E, F}
  (keyValue IP: 
    (ip_v6_address FE80: CD00: : 211E: 7 2 9 C))
```

I want to have key value pairs as output and not sure if I am writing the correct grammar. I problem that I am facing is that separator ':' can exit in value as well.
Any pointers how to fix the grammar ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because of overlapping lexer rules (multiple rules matching the same input).

The `F` char from `FE80:` is not being tokenised as a hex digit (the `F` lexer rule). However, the entire chunk `FE80:` is being tokenised as a `KEY` token.

You must realise that the lexer operates independently from the parser. The parser might be trying to match a certain token, the lexer does not "listen" to this. The lexer follows 2 very simple rules:

1. try to match as much characters as possible for a single token
2. when two or more tokens match the same characters, the rule defined first "wins"

Because of these rules, the input `F` is tokenised as an `F` token, but input like `FE` is tokenised as a `KEY` token.

The solution is to move the construction of a `KEY` from the lexer to a `key` parser rule as shown below:

```
grammar IPV6;

key_value
 : key ':' ip_v6_address
 ;

key
 : '[' string ']'
 | string
 ;

ip_v6_address
 : h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | h16? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | ((h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | (((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' h16 ':' ls32
 | ((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16 ':' ls32
 | (((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' ls32
 | ((((((h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16 ':')? h16)? '::' h16
 ;

h16
 : hexdig hexdig hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig hexdig
 | hexdig
 ;

hexdig
 : digit
 | (A | B | C | D | E | F)
 ;

ls32
 : h16 ':' h16
 | ip_v4_address
 ;

ip_v4_address
 : dec_octet '.' dec_octet '.' dec_octet '.' dec_octet
 ;

dec_octet
 : digit
 | non_zero_digit digit
 | D1 digit digit
 | D2 (D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4) digit
 | D2 D5 (D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5)
 ;

digit
 : D0
 | non_zero_digit
 ;

non_zero_digit
 : D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 | D8 | D9
 ;

string
 : (STRING_ATOM | hexdig)+
 ;

D0 : '0';
D1 : '1';
D2 : '2';
D3 : '3';
D4 : '4';
D5 : '5';
D6 : '6';
D7 : '7';
D8 : '8';
D9 : '9';

A : [aA];
B : [bB];
C : [cC];
D : [dD];
E : [eE];
F : [fF];

STRING_ATOM : [g-zG-Z/._-];

WS : [ \t\r\n] + -> skip;
```

resulting in the following parse tree:

[image]